# Error with python3 tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, tkinter

Here is mi code from ***Python3.6***  and ***Ubuntu 17.10***

> It is write with ***Atom*** and will be implemented on *Jupyter
>   Notebook*

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

> **Here start the error**

```
 class Aplicacion():
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry('300x200')
            self.root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
            self.root.configure(bg = 'red')
            self.root.title('Cachonerismo')
            self.nombre = StringVar()
            self.respuesta = StringVar()
            self.txt = ttk.Entry(self.root,textvariable = self.nombre)
            self.txt.pack(side = TOP)
            self.txt1 = ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.respuesta)
            self.txt1.pack(side = BOTTOM)
            self.btn = ttk.Button(self.root, text = 'Mostrar', command = self.saluda).pack(side = LEFT)
            self.bcl = ttk.Button(self.root, text='Cerrar', command = self.root.destroy).pack(side = RIGHT)
            self.root.mainloop()

        def saluda(self):

            self.a = self.nombre.get(self)
            self.respuesta.set(a)


    app = Aplicacion()
```

And here is the *error* i get

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tkinterTest.py", line 23, in saluda
    self.a = self.nombre.get(self)
TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Change `StringVar` to `StringVar()`.

Comment: Thanks but now i get this error 

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tkinterTest.py", line 23, in saluda
    a = self.nombre.get(self)
TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [the chunk of code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py) failing:

```
class StringVar(Variable):
    """Value holder for strings variables."""
    _default = ""
    def __init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None):
        """Construct a string variable.
        MASTER can be given as master widget.
        VALUE is an optional value (defaults to "")
        NAME is an optional Tcl name (defaults to PY_VARnum).
        If NAME matches an existing variable and VALUE is omitted
        then the existing value is retained.
        """
        Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)

    def get(self):
        """Return value of variable as string."""
        value = self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        return str(value)
```

You have to "call" the class to instantiate it:

```
self.nombre = StringVar()
self.respuesta = StringVar()
```

Comment: change `get(self)` => `get()`. Anytime you call `X.some_function()`, `X` is automatically passed as the first positional argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks dude i cant believe it was something so dumb

Comment: _"You have to call the class to instantiate it with an argument of type Variable"_ - that statement is incorrect. You don't have to give any argument at all to instantiate it. As you can see in the code you posted, `master`, `value`, and `name` are all optional.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, I was forgetting that it inherits from `Variable` - will fix